# 2 local repositories sharing a remote repository

Tags: git, version-control, repository

I have 2 folders: my Netbeans and VisualStudio folders, each containing projects.

Is there a way for them to use the same Bitbucket repository, without having to change their location? I tried making 2 local repositories, but when changing one, it asks me to pull, and it adds everything from the remote repository in the curent one. I don't want that to happen, obviously.

Comment: Like a git submodule?

Comment: You can make as many local copies of a single remote repo as you'd like to, actually. You can set up two different branches for each local folder, and merge them when necessary.

Comment: I don't want them to be merged.

Comment: If these are two completely different projects, why use a single repository then?

Comment: Since I want to group them in a folder named "School projects" no matter the language used. But I want to keep them in the original folders. Not possible?

Comment: Well, you can use [git subtree](http://blogs.atlassian.com/2013/05/alternatives-to-git-submodule-git-subtree/) for this... but I admit I'd rather solve this with a simple manager script (working with separate repositories).

Comment: That means that I have to create a repository for each of my projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I hear you correctly,  You want a single (or small number) of repositories in bitbucket, but you want to use then for a potentially large number of independent projects, thus saving money, correct?

Your options are

- Single large repo with a project per branch (messy, all projects see all branches and tags)
- git --namespace (check the git man page)

I use git --namespace= for this, because it allows each "project" to have branches and tags without ever seeing each other.
Note that regardless of what method you use to do this, a git-pull or git-fetch will **always** retrieve a full copy of all the repository objects.

https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitnamespaces.html

Comment: Well I don't want my Visual Studio projects to get pulled into the Netbeans folder. I guess there's no way to do it than put everything into a folder and just use it like that.